# regular expression replace removes first and last character when using $1

Tags: regex, replace

I have string like this:

```
&breakUp=Mumbai;city,Puma;brand&
```

where Mumbai;city and Puma;brand are filters(let say) separated by comma(,). I have to add more filters like Delhi;State.

I am using following regular expression to find the above string:

```
&breakUp=.([\w;,]*).&
```

and following regular expression to replace it:

```
&breakUp=$1,Delhi;State&
```

It is finding the string correctly but while replacing it is removing the first and last character and giving the following result:

```
&breakUp=umbai;city,Puma;bran,Delhi;State&
```

How to resolve this?
Also, If I have no filters I don't want that first comma. Like

```
&breakUp=&
```

should become

```
&breakUp=Delhi;State&
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your expression is just fine, there are two extra `.` in there, that we would remove those:

```
&breakUp=([\w;,]*)&
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLIDum/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

To bypass `&breakUp=&`, we can likely apply this expression:

```
&breakUp=([^&]+)&
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPgWGG/1/)

Comment: OP maybe you can explain why you put those dots there; what did you hope they would accomplish?

Comment: @Emma Just one more doubt. If I have no filters before then after replace I don't want that first comma. Like &breakUp=& should become &breakUp=Delhi;State&How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be the leading and trailing period, they are matched to any character.

Try using this regex:

```
&breakUp=([\w;,]*)&
```